# Microchip Studio not showing ATATMEL-ICE

Tags: microchip, atmel, atmelstudio, jtag

I have Microchip studio 7.02594 and unable to use ATATMEL-ICE since is not showing under device programming.
[image]

I got below error when start microchip studio.

[image]

Below is my device manager

[image]

I have tries to reinstall drive using zadig. Change driver to all below options:

1. WinUSB
2. LibusbK
3. Lilusb-win32
4. WinUSB(Microsoft)

Non is working.

I also try the ATATMEL-ICE on another computer and is fully functioning.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Maybe an issue with your keyboard. If possible try to switch to another one. Or check what happens if you start the Studio without a plugged keyboard.

Comment: @Mike Tried it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

In Microchip Studio, try opening Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Backend Agent, and uncheck `Start Local Backend`.

Now repeat, but re-check the same option.

I've experienced loss of connection/crashes during debug sessions maybe a few times a year resulting in the ICE not appearing, and restarting the backend agent always makes it re-appear.

Comment: I have tried this multiple times but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I have found a solution. The reason was probably a Windows update. After installing two additional Intel USB drivers at "Windows Updates"/ "Optional Updates" / "Driver Updates" the communication with my Atmel ICE worked again. Maybe this helps one or the other.

[image]